# Включение всех репозиториев CentOS 7 для установки с yum

Tags: linux, centos, yum

Пытаюсь установить виртулку с  BRO-NIDS. 
Установил CentOS 7 и попытался поставить сопутствующие пакеты, однако yum пишет, что репозиториев просто нет. Проверил в папке, они есть.
Попытался их включить командами:

```
yum-config-manager --enable CentOS*
yum-config-manager --enable *
```

Однако, вместо обещанной документацией

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html

Вижу следующую картину:
[image: отсутствие yum конфигуратора]

К сожалению я новичок в CentOS и мне хотелось бы узнать, как включить yum-config-manager, чтобы я  мог включить пакеты, а так же альтернативные методы их включения.

При всем при этом ситуация осложняется тем, что yum ничего не грузит, так как репозитории не включены.

Comment: А пакет `yum-utils` установлен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо установить пакет:

> yum-utils - Utilities based around the yum package manager

Этот пакет и содержит утилиту yum-config-manager

Comment: yum не работает, так как все репозитории выключены, необходимо установить его через rpm. Вопрос состоит как это сделать. То, что нужно установить этот пакет, это кепски.

Comment: А как Вы умудрились поставит систему БЕЗ yum ?!  Ведь на предпоследнем шаге установки дистрибутива работает именно yum. Ну ладно, раз нет, значит - нет!  Тогда надо надо ЛЮБЫМ способом скачать с репозитария пакет yum.rpm и установить его командой rpm -i yum<версия>.rpm

Comment: Не знаю, поставил последний CentOS Stable. Но попробую